# Boto3 Cloudwatch API ELBv2 returning empty datapoints

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am writing a script to pull back metrics for ELBv2 (Network LB) using Boto3 but it just keeps returning empty datapoints. I have read through the AWS and Boto docs, and scoured here for answers but nothing seems to be correct. I am aware CW likes everything the be exact and so I have played with different dimensions, different time windows, datapoint periods, different metrics, with and without specifying units etc to no avail.

My script is here:-

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import boto3
from pprint import pprint
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta


def initialize_client():
    client = boto3.client(
        'cloudwatch',
        region_name='eu-west-1'
    )

    return client


def request_metric(client):
    response = client.get_metric_statistics(
        Namespace='AWS/NetworkELB',
        Period=300,
        StartTime=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=5),
        EndTime=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=1),
        MetricName='NewFlowCount',
        Statistics=['Sum'],
        Dimensions=[
            {
                'Name': 'LoadBalancer',
                'Value': 'net/nlb-name/1111111111'
            },
            {
                'Name': 'AvailabilityZone',
                'Value': 'eu-west-1a'
            }
        ],
    )

    return response


def main():
    client = initialize_client()

    response = request_metric(client)

    pprint(response['Datapoints'])

    return 0


main()
```

Comment: Where is the client getting the credentials from? Make sure the creds are for the account that the metrics are in.

Comment: Getting metrics from CloudWatch is notoriously difficult. I find it easiest to start by using the AWS CLI `list-metrics` command to see what metrics are available, then try to match the parameters in the program. Try playing with the `Period` too.

Comment: @UnkindnessofDatapoints the creds come from the credentials file. These creds have access to the account that the metrics are coming from.
 - JohnRotenstein I'll try going through the CLI first, see if I can get that to kick back some datapoints. I've tried different periods, so I don't think it's that, unless ELBv2 uses some obscure period that isnt documented

Comment: Code seems to be fine (I used it to get data out). Try graphing the metric in the CloudWatch Console, open the source tab and check that all dimensions match. Also check that there is data on the graph for the requested range, 5 days ago to 1 day ago.